# Recommendation on Database Upgrade

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

> Mysql 8.0 vs Mysql 5.7  performance comparison

At present in my production , I'm using mysql 5.7 version.
I want to upgrade my database to mysql8 .

I need a performance comparison among these three.

After searching Mysql5.7  vs Mysql 8.

My findings are the followings :

```
 Creating Role 
 Invisible index 
 ...etc
 Insert operations are slower because of binary logging
 and we can disable it.
 Use slightly more RAM than 5.7 version
```

But what i really need is a comparison based on performance .
Connection handling, thread, pooling , max user , max connection, processing,CPU usage,memory something like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't nitpick on these most likely minor performance differences.  The two major reasons for upgrading to 8+ are that 5.7 might not be supported at some point and that 8+ supports new features such as analytic functions.  If you need 8+, then go ahead and upgrade.

Comment: Do you have idea about  Oracle 18c and mysql 5.7 ??regarding performance

Comment: They are different beasts entirely, and again there are reasons why you might choose one over the other.

Comment: Okay. I need to handle at least 20,000  simultaneous thread/connection. Using mysql 5.7  , i can handle only 1000 simultaneous thread/connection. And my server is well capable of 40000 user .

Comment: so can you say that performance will be twice faster , if i switch into oracle.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, here's no clear cut answer for you. 90% of the performance is defined by database design and implementation, not the actual version of MySQL used.

The ability to handle load and stress is mostly the same between versions. Some things under the same configurations may be performing better on the newer version, some other things on older.

Most metric in your list (handling, thread, pooling, max user, max connection, processing, CPU usage, memory, etc) are usually fine tuneable on both my.cnf and OS sysctl level. Even kernel tweaks can have an effect.

So, in general, 90% of people can't see the performance difference. On the other hand, 90% also fail at doing proper performance tests too.